# Trying to understand my level of privacy with a VPN in play, but also routing DNS directly to root servers

Tags: domain-name-system, openvpn, pfsense, privacy, unbound

When I run a http://dnschecks.tools I get the following:

[image]

Given I'm using pfSense with Unbound and OpenVPN, I'm doing my own DNS queries to the root servers. The IP listed on IPXO is my VPN IP, and on DNS resolvers I can see my ISP IP. This got me worried, but I'm wondering if I can see my IP because I'm doing queries via the browser on my machine, but a server wouldn't.

So my main questions are:

1. Is it normal that my DNS resolver is my IP? I think so since I am the resolver.
2. While using the VPN (as is the case) I hit a server, can that server extract any information shown in the image above? I guess they know the IPXO IP, which is the VPN IP, but could they somehow get to my IP via the information shown in the DNS resolvers?
3. Can I assume that my DNS queries are also going through the VPN just based on that report? Is there a linux command I could test for this?

I guess what got me confused is as I was testing DNS + VPN, all sites that test DNS Leaks, show a leak because my ISP IP, is seen on the screenshot above and in all those sites. But as far as I understand it, I don't think that's a problem in my setup. In the test seen next, they actually use the location of the DNS server, instead of the location of the VPN IP, which made it look scarier, since it's accurate:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The way that these DNS leak test sites work is by providing your browser with some random names to lookup within the domain for which they control the authoritative server. The server then logs the IP address that make the DNS requests. The information is collated and presented to you.

In your case the IP address that made the DNS request was apparently from BT in Liverpool, UK (take that with a huge glug of ipgeolocaton snake oil). This should be considered a DNS leak as your DNS queries are going outside of your tunnel. Ideally, your DNS queries (and all traffic) should go through the tunnel so that your home IP address is not leaked. In that case the VPN server exit address would be seen by the testing site.

If all of your traffic is not going through the tunnel then all of the information above could be harvested by any site you visit.

If you have not already, consider enabling qname-minimisation in unbound.
WireGuard is generally faster than OpenVPN.

Comment: > If you have not already, consider enabling qname-minimisation in unbound. WireGuard is generally faster than OpenVPN. ---

Thank you, WireGuard AFAIK is still not well supported in PfSense, it was then it was taken out.

Comment: > make the DNS requests ---

But it is correct that is my IP doing the requests, I do not forward them to BT, I resolve all the queries by querying the root servers. So technically it's not incorrect, the DNS server is my IP.

Comment: "I resolve all the queries by querying the root servers." Impossible as the root servers are not recursive (so they won't give you details they don't know about, an they know about only the TLDs), so if your first query might be to them, then next one has to be on TLD nameservers, and so on to various nameservers untile destination.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal to have all traffic go through the VPN. In that case the DNS servers will see your exit IP address as generally all outboud traffic is NATed. As the DNS servers are seeing your real IP address this would normally be considered a DNS leak

Comment: Can someone flag this answer to be made into a comment on the other answer please. Also, then delet this comment  - thanks.